# Adding all values for a particular column of a pandas data frame and dividing by sum by index (pandas, python) - ADDING AS ANOTHER COLUMN IN DATAFRAME

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

**THIS HAS TO BE A FAST CODE AS I HAVE A LOT OF DATA **

I have a data frame which has multiple same index eg:

Index is the following:

```
A 
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
D
D
D
D
```

And column df['random'] has some values eg:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 100 101 102
```

Now I want to create a new column in the same dataframe which takes the sum over each unique index point and divides original value by the sum of the values for that particular index.

Eg for d['adjusted_random'] for the first entry of A I would like to get 1/6, second entry would be 2/6, third entry 3/6 and forth entry 5/11 (B sums to 11), etc...

Please could somebody help

Comment: The only problem is, I want to add it as another column in the dataframe, but the above method mentioned is too slow (for large dataframe), could anybody come up with a faster approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Answer

```
def argunsort(s):
    n = s.size
    u = np.empty(n, dtype=np.int64)
    u[s] = np.arange(n)
    return u

def gsum(g, v):
    g, v = np.asarray(g), np.asarray(v)
    n = g.size
    a = g.argsort(kind='mergesort')
    i = argunsort(a)
    gs, vs = g[a], v[a]
    lg = np.append(np.where(gs[:-1] != gs[1:])[0], n - 1)
    cn = np.diff(np.append(-1, lg))
    cs = vs.cumsum()
    sm = np.diff(np.append(0, cs[lg]), 1)
    return (v / np.repeat(sm, cn))[i]
```

***Demonstration***

```
df.insert(1, 'adjusted_random', gsum(df.index.values, df.random.values))
df

   random  adjusted_random
A       1         0.166667
A       2         0.333333
A       3         0.500000
B       4         0.444444
B       5         0.555556
C       6         0.285714
C       7         0.333333
C       8         0.380952
D     100         0.330033
D     101         0.333333
D     102         0.336634
```

***timing***

[image]

## Old Answer

Use `transform`

```
df.random / df.groupby(level=0).random.sum()

A    0.166667
A    0.333333
A    0.500000
B    0.444444
B    0.555556
C    0.285714
C    0.333333
C    0.380952
D    0.330033
D    0.333333
D    0.336634
Name: random, dtype: float64
```

Create new column

```
df.assign(adjusted_random=df.random / df.groupby(level=0).random.sum())

   random  adjusted_random
A       1         0.166667
A       2         0.333333
A       3         0.500000
B       4         0.444444
B       5         0.555556
C       6         0.285714
C       7         0.333333
C       8         0.380952
D     100         0.330033
D     101         0.333333
D     102         0.336634
```

---

***alternatives***

```
df.random.div(df.groupby(level=0).random.transform('sum'))
df.random.div(df.random.sum(level=0))  # @NickilMaveli
```

Comment: Even shorter - `df.random.div(df.random.sum(level=0))`

Comment: The only problem is, I want to add it as another column in the dataframe, but the above method mentioned is too slow (for large dataframe), could anybody come up with a faster approach?